# How read data sent by Client with Spark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest, spark-java

I have to read some data sent by Client using Spark (a framework for Java).

This is the code of client's post request. I am using jQuery.

```
$.post("/insertElement", 
{item:item.value, value: value.value, dimension: dimension.value });
```

The code of server:

```
post(new Route("/insertElement") {
        @Override
        public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
            String item = (String) request.attribute("item");
            String value = (String) request.attribute("value");
            String dimension = (String) request.attribute("dimension");
            Element e = new Element(item, value, dimension);
            ElementDAO edao = new ElementDAO();
            edao.insert(e);
            JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject( e );
            return json; 
        }
    });
```

I am using Spark so I only have to define the route. 
I would like to store in a database the data sent by client, but all the attributes are null.

I think that this way isn't correct. How can I read the sent data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They way you send your data, using HTTP `POST`, you're posting the JSON as request **body**, not as request **attributes**. This means you shouldn't use `request.attribute("item")` and the others, but instead parse the request body to a Java object. You can use that object to create the `element` and store it using the `DAO`.

Answer (score 3):

You will need something like this:

```
post(new Route("/insertElement") {
    @Override
    public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {

        String body = request.body();
        Element element = fromJson(body, Element.class);
        ElementDAO edao = new ElementDAO();
        edao.insert(e);
        JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject( e );
        return json; 
    }
});


public class Element {

    private String item;
    private String value;
    private String dimension;

    //constructor, getters and setters

}

public class JsonTransformer {

    public static String toJson(Object object) {
        return new Gson().toJson(object);
    }

    public static <T extends Object> T  fromJson(String json, Class<T> classe) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, classe);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it would be best to have a single global instance of Gson to avoid creating an instance on each request

Answer (score 1):

try using request.queryParams("item") and so on.

Comment: This is for GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the JSON I'm sending in my request

```
    { 'name': 'Rango' }
```

This is how I've configured my Controller to parse request body.

```
    public class GreetingsController {
        GreetingsController() {
            post("/hello", ((req, res) -> {
                Map<String, String> map = JsonUtil.parse(req.body());
                return "Hello " + map.get("name") + "!";
            })));
        }
    }

    public class JsonUtil {
        public static Map<String, String> parse(String object) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(object, Map.class);
    }
```