# Cannot post body to Spark REST API using Kotlin

Tags: json, rest, gradle, kotlin, spark-java

I'm trying to follow [this Spark tutorial to create a REST API using Kotlin](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2017/01/28/using-spark-with-kotlin.html), and I'm struggling to post data on the JSON body

I would like to post the data in the body, like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdHJ1c3R5YXBwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJ1c2Vycy8xMzAwODE5MzgwIiwiZXhwIjoxNDg5OTgwNTI2fQ.5ZJG9GyhG-OCXg0C510MBFs9EQHdE909s4hpNxnM6LU"}' http://localhost:4567/tokens
```

However this would get a null value in my Kotlin file, line 20

```
/**
 * REST API for getting tokens
 * Created by juanma on 15/3/17.
 */

import spark.Spark.get
import spark.Spark.post
import spark.Spark.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    get("/hello") { req, res -> "Hello World" }
    path("/tokens") {
        get("") { req, res ->
            createToken()
        }
        // TODO check this instead, so I can get the params from the body
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113863/3923525
        post("") { req, res ->
            val token = req.queryParams("token")
            val verifiedToken = retrieveToken(token)
            res.type("application/json")
            jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(verifiedToken)
        }
    }
}

fun createToken(): String {
    val jwtProvider: JwtProvider = JwtProvider()
    val jwt: String = jwtProvider.createJwt()
    return jwt
}

fun retrieveToken(jwt: String): String {
    val jwtProvider: JwtProvider = JwtProvider()
    return jwtProvider.verifyJwt(jwt)
}
```

Setting the token in the URL seems to work, but this isn't what I'm trying to do:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:4567/tokens' -d 'token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdHJ1c3R5YXBwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJ1c2Vycy8xMzAwODE5MzgwIiwiZXhwIjoxNDg5OTgwNTI2fQ.5ZJG9GyhG-OCXg0C510MBFs9EQHdE909s4hpNxnM6LU'
```

I'm using Gradle, and here's my `build.gradle`, just in case:

```
group 'com.github.juanmougan'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.1"
    compile group: 'com.sparkjava', name: 'spark-core', version: '2.5.5'
    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-kotlin', version: '2.8.7'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742633/how-read-data-sent-by-client-with-spark/30113863#30113863), which uses Spark and Java and parses the body manually. So I tried to use this in a sample, brand new Spark/Maven/Java project, but it wouldn't even compile. In this line

```
JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(element);
```

the class `JSONObject` cannot be imported. So I guess this is a loose end.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` resides in `org.json:json`, you might want to add that package.

If you want to use Jackson instead, have a look at e.g. http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial (to actually use Jackson, you need at least `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core`, and also `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess the example I posted doesn't work, since it uses code a little different. I'll try to use Jackson